# Is possible to associate models with current time conditions?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

Is possible to get two models associated with current time condition?

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = array(
        'ForumBan',
        'ForumBanActive' => array(
            'className' => 'ForumBan',
            'conditions' => array('ForumBanActive.end_time >' => time()) // fatal error
        ),
    );
}
```

I don't want to add this condition every time i call `find` on ForumBan model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## like i said, thanks @burzum for advice, but copy-past solution from my answer isn't cool, shame on you!

Following @burzum answer i got wanted result.

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->hasOne['ForumBanActive']['conditions'] = array('ForumBanActive.end_time >' => time()));
}

public $hasOne = Array(
    'ForumBan',
    'ForumBanActive' => array('className' => 'ForumBan'),
    'UserFile',
    'BlogProfile',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic lesson in php OOP: You can't call methods and functions in  object property declarations. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Set the association in the __construct() method of the model or use bindModel():

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->hasOne['ForumBanActive']['conditions'] = array('ForumBanActive.end_time >' => time()));
}

public $hasOne = Array(
    'ForumBan',
    'ForumBanActive' => array('className' => 'ForumBan'),
    'UserFile',
    'BlogProfile',
);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but why you repost my anwer?